# Mock OData Client's Container using Moq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, odata, moq

I am using OData V4 client to create proxy inside my asp.net mvc 5. I want to unit test the controllers using Moq. Is there any way I can mock the OData service response by container. Below is the OData container instantiator:

```
    public static class ControlEntityContextHelper
    {
         /// <summary>
         /// Returns OData service context
         /// </summary>
         /// <returns></returns>
         public static Container GetEntityContext()
         {
             // create the container
             var container = new Container(new Uri("http://localhost/services/odata/"));
             container.Timeout = 1800;
             return container;
          }
     }
```

Below is the MVC Controller:

```
    public JsonResult GetEmployees(string employeeId)
    {
        var odataContext = ControlEntityContextHelper.GetEntityContext();
        var employee = odataContext.Employees.Where(emp => emp.EmployeeId == employeeId);
        return Json(employee, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Based on what you willing to do "I want to unit test the controllers". I would suggest to add another layer for your data. Repository for example. According to S.O.L.I.D your controller doing too much staff.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this:

```
public interface IEmployeeRepository
{
    Employee GetById(string id);
}

public class EmployeeRepository: IEmployeeRepository
{
    public Employee GetById() {//access to OData}
}
```

And then change your controller to

```
public JsonResult GetEmployees(string employeeId)
  {
        var employee = employeeRepository.GetById(employeeId);
        return Json(employee, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

Then you will be able to easily your Data Access Layer.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. We are actually doing the same way as you suggested. But I thought, wouldn't there be any support inherently from Moq, like we do mocking on EF's DbContext and IDbSet